# Run Javascript in Chrome through Applescript got "Missing Value"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, applescript

I'm writing a short applescript to click a website. There's a button in the webpage:

```
<input type="button" id="loginout" class="login" value="断开网络">
```

My script

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    repeat with w in windows
        set i to 1
        repeat with t in tabs of w
            if URL of t starts with "https://wlan.ct10000.com/loginsuccess.jsp" then
                set active tab index of w to i
                set index of w to 1
                exit repeat
            end if
            set i to i + 1
        end repeat
    end repeat

    delay 1
    execute front window's active tab javascript "document.getElementById(\"loginout\").childNodes[0].click()"
end tell
```

The script keeps returning "missing value".
Any suggestions?